# How to send a list from a form to another one

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, list

I have two forms in a Windows Forms project: `Form1` and `aCurso`.

I'm trying to send a List with objects of a class called `curso` (I mean: `List<curso>`) from `Form1` to `aCurso`.

But Visual Studio show this:

> Accessibility inconsistency: The type of parameter `List<curso>` is less accessible than the method `aCurso.aCurso(List<curso>)`.

So, here is the code from `Form1`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _18_05_18
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<curso> cursos = new List<curso>();
        private void btnAC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form f = new aCurso(cursos);
            f.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's code from `aCurso`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _18_05_18
{
    public partial class aCurso : Form
    {
        List<curso> cursos = new List<curso>();
        public aCurso(List<curso> cursos)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.cursos = cursos;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's code from class `curso`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _18_05_18
{
    class curso
    {
        private string nombre;
        public curso(string nombre)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expose a public method signature where some of the parameter types of the signature are not public. It wouldn't be possible to call the method from outside since the caller couldn't construct the parameters required.

All you have to do is make `curso` class public

```
public class curso
{
    private string nombre;
    public curso(string nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```